# Laravel on laradock can't seem to connect to mysql on docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laradock

Laravel can't seem to connect to mysql on laradock on docker.
How Should I fix it?
heres
.env in laravel project

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dcl
DB_USERNAME=developer
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
```

.env in laradock

```
### MYSQL #################################################

MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=dcl
MYSQL_USER=developer
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| dcl          |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

```
$  docker-compose exec workspace php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cleaning and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669


  > 669|             throw new QueryException(


  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dcl", "developer", "mysql", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit .env file in laravel

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

↓

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```